# *ngIf on password validation not working Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I cant seem to figure out what the issue is I have a form input like so..

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="password">Change Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}">
</div>
```

and then below it I have..

```
<div *ngIf="!password.valid && (password.dirty || password.touched)" class="password-reminder">
    <p>Your password must be over 8 characters and include an uppercase letter, a number and a special character</p>
</div>
```

now if I dont have a valid password and its been touched nothing happens, but I do know the validation is working because the button on my form is disabled until I put the password In correctly..

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? why wont the div show itself??

**EDIT** 
It works if I take away `&& (password.dirty || password.touched)` but I only want to show the message If they enter a not valid password and untouch..

I can see in my dev tools that the classes are being applied

but it doesnt dissapear when my password is valid..

**EDIT 2**

I am using template driven forms

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use like this -> !password.valid && password.dirty && password.touched.
Because when touched happens, It will be dirty also.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) on your Input field.

```
<input #passwordField="ngModel" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}">
```

Make sure to update the references to `password` with `passwordField` in your template.

```
<div *ngIf="!passwordField.valid && (passwordField.dirty || passwordField.touched)" class="password-reminder">
    <p>Your password must be over 8 characters and include an uppercase letter, a number and a special character</p>
</div>
```

Since you are using template driven forms, there is no corresponding `password` property in your component, and hence most use a template reference variable. You can find a demonstration of this method [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages).

Comment: Getting this error `Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!`

Comment: Aah, okay. Change your template reference variable to have a different name, e.g. `#passwordField="ngModel"`. And then also update any references to it in the template.

Comment: Im getting this error now `Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined`

Comment: You need to update the references in your template. Use `passwordField` instead of `password` in your template. I updated the answer, check the error div.

Comment: Yeah no I have done that and still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add this part to the input field(a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars))

```
#passwordField="ngModel"
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="password">Change Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}" #passwordField="ngModel">
</div>

<div *ngIf="!passwordField.valid && (passwordField.dirty || passwordField.touched)" class="password-reminder">
    <p>Your password must be over 8 characters and include an uppercase letter, a number and a special character</p>
</div>
```

Then it should work. Read more about template driven forms in [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages).

Comment: Getting this error `Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!`

Comment: Is there a variable in your ts file named as `password`?

Comment: Yeah its part of the [(ngModel)]

Comment: I updated the answer. Try now.. I chnaged `password` to `passwordField`

Comment: Im getting this error now `Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined`

Comment: Create a stackblitz and share.

Answer (score 0):

As Others said You should use an element variable like **#passwordElement="ngModel"**

have a look at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xan9ad?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: THere are already two answers with same content, what's different in yours?

Comment: @PardeepJain  i saw the person who asked question is still commenting for other's answers that its not working , so I provided stackblitz for him.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to provide the template reference in your password div:

```
#password=ngModel
```

Also add **required** to your password tag like so:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" #password=ngModel pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}" required>
```

I just tested it out and it works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp reference variable. something like

```
<input #password=ngModel />
```

then use #password to do validation. Also make sure you are applying touched and dirty class correctly.